# How can I extract all the HTML tags from a page. Not the data between the tags

Tags: awk, sed

Sorry if it’s a newbie question. I’ve been googling for an hour and I also checked several questions on this site but I can’t seem to figure it out.

I’m trying to extract all the HTML tags (elements) from a few different pages. I don’t need the data between the HTML tags. I only need the tags that are being used, comments, etc.

So the output I’m looking for is whatever is between <> I guess. As an example, if the code is

```
<head> title </head>
<body id=“body text”> blah blah blah </body>
```

I’d like the output to be:

```
<head> </head>
<body id=“body text”> </body>
```

Thanks a lot in advance and sorry if it’s a silly question.

Comment: Have you tried XSLT?

Comment: if you want the comments, etc. too (`I only need the tags that are being used, comments, etc.`) then include them in your posted sample input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want whatever between <>, try:

```
sed -n  's/.*\(<.*>\).*/\1/p' xx.html
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: That doesn't work at all, I can't imagine why you say it's exactly what you were looking for. Just try it on the posted sample input and it definitely will not produce the posted expected output.

Comment: It works. I just ran the source code of this page. Here's the output:
https://pastebin.com/53RifYiw

That's what I wanted. Some of the initial opening tags are missing but that's okay for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Perl

```
$ perl -0777 -ne ' while(/(<.+?>)/g) { print "$1\n" } ' input.txt
<head>
</head>
<body id=“body text”>
</body>

$
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a file with following content:

```
<a><B>
nothing
<blabla>
</blabla>
</B>
</a>
```

In order to get the tags contents, I used following command:

```
grep -o "<[a-zA-Z0-9]*>" testtttt.txt
```

Which yielded following result:

```
<a>
<B>
<blabla>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried it and it worked. But it stripped out some stuff between the tags. The previous solution worked. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Tags aren't always alpha-numeric words. You want `grep -o '<[^>]*>'` but that won't handle comments or cases where a string contains `<...>`.